# Bootstrap 3 cols same height (only CSS)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list of products on a prestashop website using Bootstrap 3.
All products have names and descriptions of different lenght.

The problem is that if they are not the same size there is an offset.

---

**How could I set the same height for each line from the .row ?**

I would like to align all border-bottom

Link to [my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alex197/uyczmL6j/3/)

**Do not take into account JavaScript, it's just used to generate HTML.*

```js
function gen() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}

for(var i=0;i<=20;i++){
  var e = $(".ajax_block_product").first().clone();
  e.find(".title").text(gen()+" "+gen()+" "+gen());
  $(".row").append(e);
}
```

```css
img{width:50%;}

.ajax_block_product {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <img src="http://bioritmefestival.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/img-test.png">
    <div class="title">Item name</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add below CSS code in your css file:

```
.row {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: -webkit-wrap;
 flex-wrap: -moz-wrap;
 flex-wrap: -ms-wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this CSS

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

In Bootstrap 4 you could just add the classes `d-flex flex-wrap` but in Bootstrap 3 this in not available yet